# how to unzip/uncompress segmented zip files?

Tags: zip

I downloaded a document, which is compressed as zip file and segmented, 
their names are :

`document.z01` `document.z02` `document.zip`

I'm at a loss on how to unzip them.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to concatenate all the files into a single file, and then extract the single file.

```
zip -F document.zip --output big_document.zip
unzip big_document.zip
```

Comment: So the first thing is to concatenate, `cat *.zip > document.zip`, right? Then, what is the purpose of the first `zip -F ...` command in your answer? Why not just `unzip document.zip`?

Comment: @becko This is for multi-part zip.